# Sorting the string value with empty space

Tags: java, string, sorting

I am studying JAVA and I have a question about Sorting string.

In the String ArrayList 
We have string value STRUCTURE is "0" + " " + "some string"

for example,

```
     | String
     | 0 AA
     | 1 BB
     | 2 AA
     | 3 AA
     | 4 CC
     | 5 BB
```

and

when we sort it, result should be

```
     | String 
     | 0 AA
     | 2 AA
     | 3 AA
     | 1 BB
     | 5 BB
     | 4 CC
```

how can I sort the String with "number string" +  " " +  " String"

thanks

update:

i tested code blow with
1 AA
2 AA
3 BBB
4 CC
5 BBB
6 AA
7 BBB
8 CC
9 ZZZ
10 QQQ

and I got

0 AA

1 AA

5 AA

4 BBB

2 BBB

6 BBB

3 CC

7 CC

9 QQQ

8 ZZZ

Comment: OP, please un accept my answer and accept the answer posted by ARS as its highly efficient then mine, so that i can delete my answer .:)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I dint really consider space and time complexity while coding it. i am not really sureits efficient enough, but it would give you anidea.

```
  List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();

        l.add("0 CC");
        l.add("1 BB");
        l.add("2 AA");
        l.add("3 AA");

    String str="";
    for(String s: l){
        str+=s+",";
    }
    String[] sArr = str.split(",");
    String temp="";
    for(int i=0; i<sArr.length;i++) {
        for(int j= i+1; j<sArr.length;j++){
            if(sArr[i].split("\\s")[1].compareToIgnoreCase(sArr[j].split("\\s")[1])>0){
                temp= sArr[j];
                sArr[j]= sArr[i];
                sArr[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(String g: sArr){
        System.out.println(g);
    }

output:
2 AA
3 AA
1 BB
0 CC
```

Comment: This is a very bad solution. In fact, I'm doubtful that it works for all cases!

Comment: @Muel it did work for the given input. can you suggest any other solution ???.. idint really consider space and time complexity while coding it

Comment: i tested ur code and I got result, I was mostly fine , but BBB part has order problems.  lol but thanks!! (I update my question and code tests result on the above)

Comment: @DcRedwing i am sure this can be done more elegantly then my code. but i was only giving you an idea.i am fine with the downvote, it;d kind if they'd also comment :)

Comment: The problem with this code is that (if it does work, which I'm not saying it doesn't) it will be *really* hard to manage/update in the future. It is much better to use a `Comparator`.

Comment: @DcRedwing i do recommend you to follow A.R.S solution. as it is more efficient :)

Comment: @Chaitanya10 I downvoted for the following reasons: 1 readability & maintainability - it's hard to glance at the code and understand it. 2 string manipulation - sorting doesn't require string manipulation at all. 3 it doesn't use the standard API - this stuff is provided for us! 4 performance - unsurprisingly the code performs horribly, and could never be used in production with a list with more than 100 elements. To be clear, I'll edit my answer below with what I think is a better solution - feel free to down-vote! :D

Comment: chaitanya10 and A.R.S thanks guys to help me. because it might be interview question in few days :( . again thanks!!

Comment: @Muel i did even mention that in my first line about performance. i was only showing a way.and yepp, you are right about sorting but wrong about using Standard API :P, and i would never down vote some ones solution just cuz, its better then mine :)

Comment: @chaitanya10 - The main reason I down-voted is not because one solution is better than someone else's, but that your solution is dangerous to use. There are a lot of people who read this site who are Java newbies and will happily copy/paste code posted here. It would be better to get them to copy/paste standard API stuff! Anyhow, sorry if I offended - I didn't mean to. Happy posting!

Comment: @Muel thats true, hahah and i was not offended or anything.i am fine with the downvotes, hey, we learn from our mistakes .. Happy posting mate :)

Comment: First of all, you don't need to sum up all the strings and split it into an array. Second, you could use a better sorting algorithm.

Comment: @shuangwhywhy i really regret this solution ... :P, if only there is a way to delete an accepted answer. Dc Redwing please un accept this answer an accept the other solutions over here so that i can delete this answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Expanding upon the `Comparator` solution (which is really the way you should go about solving this problem):

```
Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        String[] split1 = s1.split(" ");
        String[] split2 = s2.split(" ");

        int n = split1[1].compareTo(split2[1]);

        if (n == 0) {
            return Integer.valueOf(split1[0]).compareTo(
                                  Integer.valueOf(split2[0]));
        }

        return n;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`. You'll need to provide your own `Comparator` implemention, which implements your sorting requirements.